# Isosceles Triangle c#

Tags: c#

I have a lab where the user should be able to enter a height and the symbol they want for their isosceles triangle and two things we should be able to change is if they want a triangle bigger than 10 it changes to a triangle with a height of three, and if they enter an invalid character like a space, the character used in the triangle should be an asterisk. How can I determine when to switch the char to *? this is what i have so far:

```
//allow user input to print isosceles triangle
using System;
class MainClass {
  public static void Main (string[] args) {
    char character;//entry
    int height;

    Console.Write("enter character for triangle: ");
    character = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.Write("enter height for triangle: ");
    height = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
      if (height>10){
        height = 3;
      }//end if
      for(int row = 0; row<=height-1;row++){
        Console.WriteLine(new string (character, row+1));
      }//end for
      for(int row = height-1; row>=1;row--){
        Console.WriteLine(new string (character, row));
      }//end for
    Console.WriteLine("done");
  }//end main
}//end class
```

Comment: I don't understand what the `character` variable is for. What is the "character" of a triangle? What are the possible options?

Comment: the character char is the character i want the triangle to be printed out of. so if the character is # with a height of three it should print a triangle made out of #'s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to use int.TryParse to try to parse a string to an integer rather than Convert.ToInt32, because Convert will throw an exception if the input is not an integer, whereas TryParse will return a bool if the parsing was successful and will set an out parameter to the parsed value. try adding a list of allowed characters and if its not that use the *

Answer (score 1):

Make a list of the allowed characters. If the character entered by the user is not contained in this list, then it is invalid. You can treat a string as a list of characters, so you don't have to surround each individual character with single quotes.

```
var allowedCharacters = "abcdefgABCDEFG!@#$";
if (!allowedCharacters.Contains(character))
    character = '*';
```

Alternatively, you can use a regular expression, so you don't have to type each letter from a to z:

```
var allowedCharacters = "[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$]";
if (!Regex.IsMatch(character.ToString(), allowedCharacters))
    character = '*';
```

Answer (score 1):

> *"How can I determine when to switch the char to `*`?*

After you get the character from the user would be a good time to see if it's valid.

A few other notes/thoughts:

1. It's better to use `int.TryParse` to try to parse a string to an integer rather than `Convert.ToInt32`, because `Convert` will throw an exception if the input is not an integer, whereas `TryParse` will return a `bool` if the parsing was successful and will set an `out` parameter to the parsed value
2. Same thing with `Convert.ToChar`. If you just want to get a character from the user, then you can use `Console.ReadKey().KeyChar` to read the first character the user enters.
3. What if `height < 1`? Shouldn't we also use `3` if they enter `0` or a negative number?
4. If you want to see the output at the end, you should add a `Console.ReadKey()` as the last line, so the program waits for user input before exiting.
5. It's usually considered better practice to initialize a variable when it's declared if possible (like `character` and `height`).
6. We can simplify the `for` logic a little by forcing `row` to be within the range we expect, this way we don't have to do an extra mathematic operation on every iteration.

For example:

```
Console.Write("Enter the character to use when drawing the triangle: ");
char character = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;

// Check if our character is valid, and if it's not, set it to the default value
if (character == ' ')
{
    character = '*';
}

int height;
Console.Write("Enter the triangle's height: ");

if (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out height) ||
    height > 10 || height < 1)
{
    height = 3;
}

for(int row = 1; row <= height; row++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(new string (character, row));
}

for(int row = height; row > 0; row--)
{
    Console.WriteLine(new string (character, row));
}

Console.Write("Done! Press any key to exit...");
Console.ReadKey();
```

Note that if there is more than one invalid character, you can put them in a list and check if the input matches any item in the list:

```
// Check if our character is valid, and if it's not, set it to the default value

// Make a list of invalid characters
List<char> invalidCharacters = new List<char> {' ', '`', '/'};

foreach (var invalidCharacter in invalidCharacters)
{
    if (character == invalidCharacter)
    {
        character = '*';  // character was invalid, so set it to default
        break;            // and exit the loop since we're done checking
    }
}
```

Comment: super helpful! I ended up usions something similar to your last example of code and the notes were v useful, thanks

Comment: glad to help. `if (invalidCharacters.Any(c => character == c)) character = '*';` does the same thing.